# Different nuances in meaning for なら sentences

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances, tense, conditionals

I've looked at previous posts made on conditionals but still have a bit of trouble with なら. I was hoping someone could tell me the differences in meaning/nuance between the following sentences. The first two sentences came from *A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar* (p.283) and apparently do exist, but the the last two I made up and would like to know if they work at all and why/why not.

> テープレコーダーを**買う**ならテープを**くれる**はずです。(in dictionary)
>
> テープレコーダーを**買った**ならテープを**くれる**はずです。(in dictionary)
>
> テープレコーダーを**買った**ならテープを**くれた**はずです。(made up)
>
> テープレコーダーを**買う**ならテープを**くれた**はずです。(made up)

Also can you have 買っている/買っていた and くれている/くれていた？ This is probably a really stupid question but I'm obsessed with knowing all the possibilities.

よろしくおねがいします！

Answer (score 3):

Here are my interpretations of the four sentences, in the listed order.

(1) If [you] (are going to) buy a tape recorder, [I] expect [them] to give [you] tapes. *(Statement of expected outcome. Here I would interpret the tapes to come with the recorder.)*

(2) If [you] bought a tape recorder, [I] expect [them] to give [you] tapes. *(Statement of expected outcome. Tapes are supplied to those who bought recorders in the past.)*

(3) If [you] bought a tape recorder, [they] should have given [you] tapes. *(Implies the expected outcome did not occur. They recorder was bought, but no tapes were supplied.)*

(4) If [you] are going to buy a tape recorder, [they] should have given [you] tapes. *(Implies the expected outcome did not occur. Tapes should have been given to someone with the intent/promise of buying a recorder in the future.)*

買っている/くれている to me implies a steady/regular purchase, say a monthly shipment, for example. It than makes sense that one could expect a steady shipment of tapes to be supplied with it.

買っていた/くれていた is like (3) above but for regular shipments.

Edit: I realized 買っていた/くれていた does make sense.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, I really do appreciate it :)

Comment: I read somewhere that for AならB, if B is past tense then A needs to express a past state or event. Would this mean A needs to be past tense? What do you make of this? Thanks again :)

Comment: Can you try to find the source for that? I never heard anything like it.

Comment: It was in the Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar. But as for your explanation of 「テープレコーダーを買うならテープをくれたはずです。」 it makes perfect sense to me so I'm not sure why they say it.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/A-Dictionary-Basic-Japanese-Grammar/dp/4789004546

Comment: @Faolan Sorry, I removed your link to page 284 of *A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar* because the link violated the terms of service.  [See this discussion on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171488/are-links-to-copyright-material-allowed-or-not#comment507653_171489).  Espen Nielsen, please note that Faolan left a comment linking to page 284 specifically.